# WPF C# Custom UI Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox

I've created a custom TextBox with an extra property - "Label".
Is there a way to make this property visible under the "Common" catagory in the Properties Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the category attribute above your property. The namespace for this attribute is System.ComponentModel

```
[Category("Common")]
public string Label { get; set; }
```